# How to sum transactional data by nominal account and month

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, sum

Almost a complete novice at sql, trying to find my way around - I have a table of transactional data from our accounting software showing date (in dd-mm-yyyy format), nominal account and amount for each transaction. I am looking to have an output table which sums the amount posted to each nominal account within each month & year.

My current table of data:

```
Date--Nominal_Code--Amount
01/01/2015--1000-£10
03/01/2015--1000-£20
15/01/2015--2000-£50
20/01/2015--2000-£10
01/02/2015--1000-£20
15/02/2015--1000-£30
20/02/2015--1000--£15
```

My desired output:

```
Month--Year--Nominal_Code--Amount
Jan--2015--1000--£30
Jan--2015--2000--£60
Feb--2015--1000--£65
```

Sure it's very simple, but just can't get it!

Any and all help appreciated! Thanks!

Appreciate all the help so far, but I still can't get it to work. Perhaps I need to give more info as (being a novice) it may be that I'm doing something ridiculous that means it'll never work. So, I am using Microsoft Query to access a table via an ODBC link. The table is called AUDIT_JOURNAL.

I import the table and choose to view in MS Query. I then look at the View SQL option. It reads as follows:

```
SELECT AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.AMOUNT,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.FOREIGN_AMOUNT  
FROM AUDIT_JOURNAL AUDIT_JOURNAL  
WHERE (AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE>={d '2015-02-01'})
```

It returns a table of transactions with the 4 columns listed above.

I am trying to condense these into a summarise table, showing one record for each Month, Year and NOMINAL_CODE combination.

My first issue is that I do not have a Month or Year field, just the DATE field which is in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

Having tried to use DATEPART(), YEAR() or MONTH() expressions on the DATE column I repeatedly get an error saying Column Not Found.

It happens when I do the following, for example:

```
SELECT YEAR(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS Year,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.AMOUNT,  
AUDIT_JOURNAL.FOREIGN_AMOUNT  
FROM AUDIT_JOURNAL AUDIT_JOURNAL  
WHERE (AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE>={d '2015-02-01'})
```

Comment: "showing date (in dd-mm-yyyy format)" Fix that, then get back to us. And don't store '£'

Comment: Can you show us your SQL query you have created so far?

Answer (score 1):

These functions are needed for your query.

- The [`MONTHNAME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) function returns the name of the month
- The [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function returns the year

Beyond that, you need to `GROUP BY` to sum everything. Make sure you get comfortable with doing this; it's a crucial SQL skill.

Here's a first shot at the query:

```
SELECT
  MONTHNAME(`Date`) AS The_Month,
  YEAR(`Date`) AS The_Year,
  Nominal_Code,
  SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
  MONTHNAME(`Date`),
  YEAR(`Date`),
  Nominal_Code
ORDER BY
  The_Year,
  The_Month,
  Nominal_Code
```

That will give results, except notice that `February` in the results comes before `January`. That's because it's ordering by the month *name*. You'll want to order by the month *number*, which is the MySQL [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function. To have the month number be part of the query you'll also need to `GROUP BY` it:

```
SELECT
  MONTH(`Date`) AS Month_Number,
  MONTHNAME(`Date`) AS The_Month,
  YEAR(`Date`) AS The_Year,
  Nominal_Code,
  SUM(Amount) AS Total_Amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
  MONTH(`Date`),
  MONTHNAME(`Date`),
  YEAR(`Date`),
  Nominal_Code
ORDER BY
  The_Year,
  Month_Number,
  Nominal_Code
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivar - oversight on my part; I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'm just going something silly but I've tried:  SELECT
  MONTHNAME(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS The_Month,
  YEAR(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS The_Year,
  AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE,
  SUM(AUDIT_JOURNAL.AMOUNT) AS Total_Amount
FROM AUDIT_JOURNAL.AUDIT_JOURNAL
GROUP BY
  MONTHNAME(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE),
  YEAR(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE)
ORDER BY
  The_Month,
  The_Year  and I get an error saying "Could not add the table 'AUDIT_JOURNAL.AUDIT_JOURNAL'"

Comment: @Oli you have `AUDIT_JOURNAL.AUDIT_JOURNAL` in your `FROM`. You probably only want `FROM AUDIT_JOURNAL`, unless your database is also called `AUDIT_JOURNAL`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the following but get an error saying "Column not found":  SELECT
  MONTH(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS Month_Number,
  MONTHNAME(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS The_Month,
  YEAR(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE) AS The_Year,
  AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE,
  SUM(AUDIT_JOURNAL.AMOUNT) AS Total_Amount
FROM AUDIT_JOURNAL
GROUP BY
  MONTH(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE),
  MONTHNAME(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE),
  YEAR(AUDIT_JOURNAL.DATE),
  AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE
ORDER BY
  The_Year,
  Month_Number,
  AUDIT_JOURNAL.NOMINAL_CODE

Comment: @Oli could you try the query without the `ORDER BY` clause and let me know if it works?

Comment: OK; I'll play with this in SQL Fiddle for a few minutes (I don't have MySQL available otherwise) and get back to you.

Comment: @Oli, I'm having trouble with the SQLFiddle site, which happens often. I'll revisit this at lunchtime here (about an hour from now).

Comment: OK, SQLFiddle finally woke up a few minutes ago. I tried my first and second queries and both worked. The Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f78/3). Take a look and see if you find any differences between your table and what I think your table looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

For the month you can try this select

```
select  date_format(month(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m %Y') as month, nominal_code, sum(Amount)
from my_table
group by month
```